# Rating on Radio button is not stored

Tags: php, mysql, database, radio-button

I have a comment BOX, which has 5 fields, one is name, email, RATE, comment, articleid.

Rate field is a radio type, which has 5 radio buttons with value 1,2,3,4,5. IF someone click on rate my product and it should save the rated value in databse. I'm using RATE as INT in database, It stores 0 in it, If i use RATE as TEXT in database, it stores "on" in database. It is not storing rating values like 1,2,3,4,5.

**My form Code**

```
<form action="manage_comments.php" method="post">
<span class="rating">
<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rate" name="rate" value="1">
<label for="rating-input-1-5" class="rating-star"></label>

<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rate" name="rate" value="2">
<label for="rating-input-1-4" class="rating-star"></label>

<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rate" name="rate" value="3">
<label for="rating-input-1-3" class="rating-star"></label>

<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rate" name="rate" value="4">
<label for="rating-input-1-2" class="rating-star"></label>

<input type="radio" class="rating-input" id="rate" name="rate" value="5">
<label for="rating-input-1-1" class="rating-star"></label>

</span>

<input type='hidden' name='articleid' id='articleid' value='<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>' />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Publish Now"></p>

</form>
```

**My php Code**

```
<?php
if( $_POST ) 
{
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","asfi","asfi");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("aw-tech", $con);

$post_rate =  (isset($_POST['rate'])) ? $_POST['rate'] : '';

$articleid =  (int)isset($_GET['id']);
if(!is_numeric($articleid))
die('invalid article id');

$sql="INSERT INTO `aw-tech`.`comment` (cid, name, email, website, comment, timestamp,      rate, articleid) VALUES (NULL, '$_POST[name]', '$_POST[email]', '$_POST[website]', '$_POST[comment]', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '$post_rate', ".$articleid.")";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
{
die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Comment Saved";

mysql_close($con);
} 
?>
```

Secondly My articleid saves always 0.. my page id is .php?id=49 , it is 49 but if i made comment on that page, It saves my article ID always 0.

**articleid & rate Both are INT in database, I have used them as TEXT too in database but didn't work**

Comment: Make a `print_r($_POST);` and say if the results printed are the expected ones.

Comment: invalid closing of </p> also showing the db structure.

Comment: @Nomi, I fixed that </p> .. still didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found your problem. Change form declaration to:

```
<form action="manage_comments.php" method="post">
```

Remove row:

```
<input type='hidden' name='articleid' id='articleid' value='<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>' />
```

the Then PHP code from:

```
$post_rate =  (isset($_POST['rate'])) ? $_POST['rate'] : '';
$articleid =  (int)isset($_GET['id']);
```

to:

```
$post_rate = (isset($_POST['rate'])) ? $_POST['rate'] : 0;
$articleid = (int)isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : 0;
```

And for debug add this after the `$sql` variable and insert into a comment here:

```
print_r($_GET);
print_r($_POST);
echo $sql;
```

Hope it works.

Comment: I tried your code, but it doesn't made any effect... It still saves 0 in rate and articleid in database.

Comment: @user3076307, "and insert into a comment here" please put the info here or give a link to the page you are editing..

Answer (score 0):

when you post the form in action you put : manage_comments.php
so the "id" be lost!

in action you can put : `manage_comments.php?id=<?php=$_GET[id]?>`

or
after submit form 
use `$_POST[articleid]` not `$_GET['id']`

Comment: @user3076307, Did you read the comments to your question? Write an anwer to them.

Answer (score 0):

i think it supposes to be

$post_rate =  (isset($_POST['rate'])) ? $_POST['rate'] : '';

$articleid =  (int)isset($_POST['articleid']);

Comment: That doesn't work, Its save 1 as ID of anything, It doesn't save the correct ID, I have used GET

Comment: it is weird. as i tested in my computer and it gave correct ID all the time. I think you can try again and use POST

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't work. If you can email me your code, So i can fix my code according to your code. PrinceAsfi@gmail.com

Comment: The code is exactly like yours except the above line is different and i just tested $articaleid via echo not saving to database.Could you check your query if it right? i think $_POST['name'] not $_POST[name]. make sure your query is right